# spring validator @Pattern doesn't work on Integer

Tags: spring, spring-validator

I am trying a simple pattern validation:

```
@Min(value = 0, message = "invalid.amount")
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+", message = "invalid.amount")
private double amount;
```

But it gives the error like:

```
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.throwExceptionForNullValidator(ConstraintTree.java:229)
```

But this works perfectly fine:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[\\w|-]{1,5}")
private String data;
```

It seems regex doesn't work on number types.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that the @Pattern annotation will return true if a substring regex match passes. If it isn't working then your assumption may not be true.

> @Pattern(regex=,flag=)    CharSequence
>
> Checks if the annotated string matches the regular expression regex
>   considering the given flag match.

You can try change double to String and works with @Pattern normally.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+", message = "invalid.amount")
private String amount;
```

Also other way could be:

```
@DecimalMax("10.0") @DecimalMin("0.0") 
private double amount;
```